# Modify the url of my cloud service

Tags: windows, azure, service

How to change the url of windows azure application which is in cloud?
modify the url from xxx.cloudapp.net to yyy.cloudapp.net

thanks for your helps

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that! The only way is to create new cloud service and deploy your package there.

Please note that creating cloud service is nothing else but reserving the DNS name (XXX.cloudapp.net). You are not being charged for creating cloud services. You are only charged for when you deploy something on those cloud services. So you can create as many as you wish (well, I think there is some soft limit on the number of cloud services you can create, so delete the ones you are not planning to use).

When you go for production I highly suggest you to use your own custom domain (i.e. www.mycomany.com). For this, please follow the instructions [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/).